# what does the rpmbuild warning "File listed twice" ACTUALLY MEAN?

Tags: installation, rpm, rhel, rpmbuild, software-packaging

I need to specify common attributes for one of the major directories in the package, and special permission for some of it subdirs. e.g.

```
%files
%attr(-, myuser, mygroup) /opt/myapp 
%attr(750, myuser, mygroup) /opt/myapp/bin  # no exec permission to other
/etc  # this is the reason I can't use %defattr(-, myuser, mygroup)
```

I get the "file listed twice" warning on every file under /opt/myapp/bin, naturally. My question is, what does it actually mean? What does rpmbuild do with it? I can't find an answer anywhere. Can I just ignore it? What takes precedence, the first or the last occurrence?

I prefer not to list everything under `myapp` explicitly to solve this. is there any other way? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means just that - it's listed twice. ;) I've never had a problem with it, but I don't know which will win.

As a side note, you probably shouldn't list `/etc` on its own, since you don't want to own that.

Comment: This answer is wrong. If you list /etc, the rpm will "own" all files that are in %{buildroot}/etc, not in /etc.
So, listing /etc in the %files section is common practice and there isn't any real drawback

Comment: If you attempt to install two packages that try to own `/etc`, RPM will refuse to install the second one, which is why it is to be avoided.

Comment: This is true only in the case of %dir /etc. If you simply list /etc the files owned by the package are the ones inside of it but not the dir itself

Answer (score 14):

I am posting here just in case someone has the same issue and finds this old question.

Recently (how recently depends on the distro) the macro %exclude has been added to rpmbuild.

```
%files
%attr(-, myuser, mygroup) /opt/myapp
%exclude /opt/myapp/bin
%attr(750, myuser, mygroup) /opt/myapp/bin  # no exec permission to other
```

The advantage here is not as evident as having a set of files or folders to exclude:

```
%files
%attr(-, myuser, mygroup) /opt/myapp
%exclude /opt/myapp/[bin|data|whatever]
%attr(750, myuser, mygroup) /opt/myapp/bin  # no exec permission to other
%attr(777, myuser, myothergroup) /opt/myapp/data
%attr(640, myuser, myothergroup) /opt/myapp/whatever
```

Strangely the [a|b] syntax works with %exclude but not with the other directives in %files (eg I can use a regex to exclude but not to include, doh)

Comment: thanks, it worked. So I can do

    /home/oracle/scripts 
    %exclude /home/oracle/scripts/myconfig.config
   %config(noreplace) /home/oracle/scripts/myconfig.config

without the warning about duplicate file

Comment: Unfortunately on my CentOS 5.5 adding `%exclude` does not allow me to re-include files later.

Comment: While this does suppress the error, it also results in the package not including the file at all on rpmbuild 4.8.0 - which is not exactly the expected result. :)

Comment: @dannysauer you need to explicitly include the files you need after the %exclude statement. I haven't built any rpm package in a while, I gotta try it on rpmbuild 4.8.0

Comment: @Bruno9779 I did include after the exclude, just like in the examples where a directory is included, then a subdir and file inside are excluded then included. It was RHEL6, so could just be an old bug / behavior. I really need to move this process to a RHEL7 system anyway. ;)

Answer (score 10):

Change it to this:

```
%files
%dir %attr(-, myuser, mygroup) /opt/myapp
%attr(750, myuser, mygroup) /opt/myapp/bin
```

notice the `%dir` for the directory. That should get rid of the files listed twice warning.

Comment: Note that [using %dir will make it an empty directory](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html). So this isn't as useful if you need to include everything in /opt/myapp *and* custom-configure the permissions on just the bin subdir.

Comment: The link in the comment above no longer works. Use http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html instead.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this error could be that you have listed the directory as well as the files in that directory under `%files`.

Example:

```
%files
%{_bindir}/%{name}-%{version}/dir
%{_bindir}/%{name}-%{version}/dir/file
```

In this case either you just list the directory like this:

```
%files
%{_bindir}/%{name}-%{version}/dir
```

Or list directory as `%dir` then list files as well, like this:

```
%files
%dir %{_bindir}/%{name}-%{version}/dir
%{_bindir}/%{name}-%{version}/dir/file
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the current version of rpmbuild on RH 8.6 and non of these solutions are working.  As posted in the comments, %exclude removing the files and directories while %dir removes all the sub-directories and files under it unless specified.  Example where servlet_workspace is the tomcat directory path to a directory tree of 2 files and 5 directories being created for the application.

```
%files
%attr(-, tomcat, tomcat) %{servlet_workspace}
%attr(0664, tomcat, tomcat) %{servlet_workspace}/logs/%{conf_file}.sample
%attr(0775, tomcat, tomcat) %{servlet_workspace}/stitcherStuff/reboot.sh
```

Putting %dir removes all the subdirectories under servlet_workspace.

```
%files
%dir %{servlet_workspace}
%attr(0664, tomcat, tomcat) %{servlet_workspace}/logs/%{conf_file}.sample
%attr(0775, tomcat, tomcat) %{servlet_workspace}/stitcherStuff/reboot.sh
```